# How to get bash to display only a partial list of file names when using commands such as ls cp mv

Tags: command-line

Let's say I have a lot of files in a directory that take on the following names:

```
FF_01_1000
FF_01_1001
FF_01_1002
.
.
.
FF_01_9999
FF_02_1000
FF_02_1001
FF_02_1002
.
.
.
FF_02_9999
```

Now, if I type a

```
cp FF
```

into the terminal and press tab, it will autocomplete and I will get the following:

```
cp FF_0
```

Now, if I press tab again to see what options I have, bash will show all 19998 filenames. But what if I want to know the options I have up to the first level of ambiguity, or a tab like key that gives me the following output in the terminal only:

```
FF_01...
FF_02...
```

This kind of option is very useful when it comes to navigating filenames that use dates.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. Please help us help you by [edit]ing the output of  `echo $0` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: I get "bash" when I type that into the terminal.

Comment: In what way is TAB not providing "options I have up to the first level of ambiguity"? Perhaps that's the part confusing me,

Comment: TAB *once* should complete up to the first ambiguous character - you should only get the list of files if you hit TAB again afaik... unless your bash_completion is messed up

Comment: TAB shows you all the files that match what you have typed. In my example, it will try to spit out 19998 filenames and then show you a --more-- output when it has filled up the screen. However, I only want some way to get it to show two outputs instead of 19998 outputs, as in the example I have posted.

Comment: Ah, I see where I caused the confusion. I mentioned "autocomplete" which was the mistake. It's what happens after pressing tab multiple times.